# SOAP request in android, JSON response parsing

Tags: c#, android, soap, getjson, android-webservice

I want to consume the C# web service from android application..
In my project I'm using  SOAP in request for taking data back, with kSOAP 2 library, but when I'm doing "invoke" on my  ......asmx , C# backend, with this code

```
     SoapObject getWeather(String customerNumber) throws Exception {
    PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
    property.setName("LicenseId");
    property.setValue("8BEBFB9F-D9C9-4880-9225-AB50976F2975");
    property.setType(String.class);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://mobilesuite365.com",
            "GetCustomers");
    request.addProperty(property);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // It seems that it is a .NET Web service because it doesn't work
    // without next line


    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(
            "http://www.mobilesuite365.net/app2/getdata.asmx");
    transport.debug = true;
    transport.call("http://mobilesuite365.com/GetCustomers", envelope);



    return (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

I'm getting this error "XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT" , because response comes like JSON, but ksoap can handle xml format..

how to take response and handle information from response and use it in my app?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `SoapPrimitive` in stead of a `SoapObject` and convert it to `String` type

```
String response = "";
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
if (result != null)
    response = result.toString();

return response;
```

After that you should use something like `Gson` to parse the `JSON` you received.